# Discrete Mathematics (Closure Problems)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, field-theory, relations

$R = \{(x, x+1)|x \in \mathbb{Z}\}$

$\mathbb{Z}$ is the integers and could be negative or positive.

Create the closure of the the following:

a. $t(R)$ --> transitive closure of R

b. $rt(R)$ --> reflexive transitive closure of R

c. $st(R)$ --> symmetric transitive closure of R

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Work through some examples. Fix one integer and figure out everything it's related to. For example, consider $7$. We know that $(7, 8) \in t(R)$. But since $(8, 9) \in t(R)$, we know by transitivity that $(7, 9) \in t(R)$. But we can repeat this argument with $(9, 10) \in t(R)$ to get that $(7, 10) \in t(R)$. A simple induction argument would show that $(7, b) \in t(R)$ for all $b > 7$. Generalizing, we see that:
$$
t(R) = \,<_\mathbb{Z}\, = \{(a, b) \in \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \mid a < b\}
$$

See if you can figure out the other two closures.

Comment: How about if the combination of reflexive and transitive closure of R like in b

Comment: That's what "see if you can figure out the other two" means.

Answer (score 0):

You know that the transitive closure is $<$.

If a relation is reflexive then it must also contain $(x,x)$. Transitivity means it becomes $\le$.

if a relation is symmetric then if it contains $(x,y)$ then it must contain $(y,x)$. Transitivity means it becomes $\neq$.

Comment: so, what's the answer for a, b, and c?

Comment: The goal of StackExchange is not to give answers to your homeworks. I already find very nice from the two people who answered that they gave you some hints, even though you didn't care to explain what you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @Kristian: I have given all the answers above. What are you asking?